# How to implement HTML/JS with Github API to save changes in file to Repository

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages, github-api, tiddlywiki

In numerous software/web programs, including TiddlyWiki5, I have seen advanced "Save to Github" features. These features generally need use of username, repository, and password/PAT, and save changes to the actual file to the Github Repository. I would like to implement this feature in one of my programs, but have been unable to find documentation/information on how to do this, namely overriding file code and replacing it with the changed code.

Do any of you happen to know?

Comment: You mean this documentation? https://docs.github.com/en/rest (found by typing "github API" into google). If not, then please clarify what exactly it is you're unsure about.

Comment: Not exactly, @ADyson. I've gone through that specific url a few times now. What I'm really looking for is saving from inside an html file. For example, I would prompt user to type username, repository, filename, and password, and send that information via Github API to save the file into their repository at that file. The correct info on how to do that may be in the url you gave, but I at least haven't found it yet.

Comment: You need client-side Javascript, then. See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/libraries#javascript for ready-made libraries which can help you with making the necessary requests correctly. As you neeed client-side, you probably want the gh3 one.